# Adding custom file extension to netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, ide, view, codeigniter-2, assets

I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 for my developments with CodeIgniter/Bonfire.

In my controllers i'm loading my for the view needed JavaScripts via

```
Assets::add_js($this->load->view('admin/index_js', $data, true), 'inline');
```

to preparse some php variables in the JavaScript (like dynamic url's).

This forces me to save these JavaScript files witht he extension ".php" so that i can load it via

```
$this->load->view
```

All these JavaScript files are using the filename syntac

```
*_js.php
```

Since i load it via view and Assets with "inline" parameter i can't put the

```
<script>
</script>
```

tags in the script so NetBeans is not recognizing it as JavaScript and i have no syntax highlightning and no formatting options.

Any idea how i can get it that NetBeans can recognize it as JavaScript?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... got it...

One of my collegues made a change to the assets library to "erase" the script tags from assets::js inline included files:

http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/1134/assetsjs-inline_js-change-to-load-js-via-view#Item_1